# how do I force echo on for a batch file without editing the file?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong inside a microsoft batch file, and I want to preserve the file and environment it runs from as it natively would.  How can I force echo to stay on so I can find the line that is giving an error without changing their file?

Answer (score 2):

If the batch file has `Echo Off` in it, then you are pretty much out of luck unless you remove/remark that line (or change it to `Echo On`).

It's pretty safe to make a backup, REM out that line, and save it as it won't affect any functionality besides preventing Echo from being turned off.

[You Can't Make an Omelette without breaking a few eggs](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouCantMakeAnOmelette). :)

Perhaps just warn "them" of what you are going to do; If it's broken already, and they've asked you to look at it, then I doubt they'll mind. :)

Comment: +1: You can pretty much backup anything ans safely modify it.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the amount of changes if you change from one behaviour
to the other:

Just replace all

```
echo off
```

with

```
call:echo_off
```

and append the following to your batch files

```
:echo_off
@REM activate only one of the two following lines to choose the desired behaviour
REM echo off
@echo echo off supressed

goto:eof
```

Another approach:
Replace all echo calls with

```
call:echo
```

and have a funktion like

```
:echo
REM call of '@echo on' optional since 'call:echo off' will just print 'echo:off'
@REM activate only one of the two following lines to choose the desired behaviour
@echo echo:%*
@REM echo %*
@goto:eof
```

This however will change the output format for all echo commands by prepending `echo:`. when you choose the echo off suppression.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the batch file now, and then not edit it again you could have something like this at the top of your file:

```
@echo off & if "%1"=="/o" @echo on
```

and then you could just start it normal for echo off or start it with `file.bat /o` for echo off. 
If you don't want to edit the batch file at all then you are out of luck.